# Parsing exactly two elements from standard input using scanf()

Tags: c, scanf, stdin

What I am trying to achieve is to parse exactly 2 elements from stdin using scanf, otherwise print error.

I tried

```
int read = scanf("%d %d", &width, &height);
if(read > 2 || read == EOF || read < 2)
{
    printf("Invalid inputs\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

But this does not print error for some cases. Although I enter 3 elements, it just read the first 2 elements from stdin, not occurring the error message. How should I occur an error if number of elements is greater than 2?

Also Could someone please tell me what EOF means to scanf()? Wasn't EOF for a function that actually reads a file, not stdin? Are we able to use EOF with scanf()?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `scanf` call will *never* detect extra input. That's simply not how it works.

Comment: On another note, `read > 2 || read < 2` is the same as `read != 2`.

Comment: Raad a _line_ with `fgets()`..Then try `sscanf(  , "%d%d%d",...` to look for more than 2 elements in a _line_.

Comment: As for your question about EOF: look under RETURN VALUE in the manual page for `scanf`.